# How to use an API from wholesalers to populate inventory on small business website?

Tags: django

I've been building some simple websites with django and am somewhat comfortable with it, enough to use models, templates and apps at least.

Now, I'm making a website for a friends small business that will have shopping cart functionality, and will display inventory. He doesn't have anything in stock and get's it all from wholesalers, so inventory will be shown directly from wholesalers database who have an API.

Everything I could find when searching for a tutorial covered creating an API, not using one.

Do I have to have a mode or a database locally? Or is everything taken from the API as a series of get requests?

How do I pull say, all cars that are yellow, or all that are yellow made by BMW, and display on my inventory page with pagination?

Not asking for a specific set of instructions here, just a very high level overview so I know what to search for to teach myself how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consuming an api is not a django related, it 's python related. An easy way to consume an api is python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Regarding your question on how to handle the data. Both of your ways are possible with some advantages and disadvantages. If you always get the data from the api, they will be always up to date but the load time is longer. If you download all data first to you local database, you need to rebuild their datastructure but loading time it faster and you can use the power of the django orm.

A third option might be that you query the product data from the frontend via javascript so that you just have to build views to handle action such as "add to shopping basked" or "checkout".

Comment: Ah, thankyou. I thought there might be some django specific stuff to process data from an API. So it might make sense for example to automatically via a script download data from API into local database, and run once a week to synchronize? I will investigate the frontend javascript method also.

Is there any good tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: If you want to retrieve the products in the frontend directly from the wholesale api, use Angular, Vue, or React. Downloading it once per week is possible.